# How to define a variable in Django TemplateView?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I created a Django project and prepared 3 html pages. By the way, my English is not good, I apologize in advance.

Here is the views.py file example;

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
     template_name = 'home.html'

class LoginPageView(TemplateView):
     template_name = 'login.html'

class NotFoundPageView(TemplateView):
     template_name = 'login.html'
```

I want to add a variable to the home.html file. How do I define it here?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For static data you can set [`extra_context`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.extra_context) on the view (Django 2.0+)

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    extra_context = {'page_name': 'home'}
```

For dynamic data or older versions of Django, you can override [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data).

```
import random

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['number'] = random.randrange(1, 100)
        return context
```